# rewrite url using nginx

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

Anyone can help me, i want to rewrite url from

> http://localhost/auditsi/cms3/index.phpdirMod=jobseeker&dirAct=myaccount&dirPref=view_front&dirMn=lWU=

to

> http://localhost/auditsi/cms3/jobseeker/myaccount/view_front/lWU=

where `/auditsi/cms/` is directory.

my rewrite here:

```
    location / {
        }

    location /auditsi/cms3/ {
        index index.php index.html;
        rewrite ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?dirMod=$1&dirAct=$2&dirPref=$3 break;               
    }
```

I've learn from wiki nginx but never succses :(

please help me.

Comment: Didn't you forget a question mark in the original URL, did you?

Comment: ops..sorry i'm wrong. good url is http://localhost/auditsi/cms3/index.php?dirMod=jobseeker&dirAct=myaccount&dirPref=view_front&dirMn=lWU=  but my problem is same :(

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
server {
     rewrite ^/auditsi/cms3/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?dirMod=$1&dirAct=$2&dirPref=$3 break;

     location {

     }

     location /auditsi/cms3/ {
            index index.php index.html;

     }
 ....
```

Comment: it's work but only access http://localhost/auditsi/cms3/jobseeker/myaccount/view_front not http://localhost/auditsi/cms3/jobseeker/myaccount/view_front/lWU=